# How to put all the div squares on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to lay down all these square divs horizontally but when I set `display:inline-block` on the parent div, everything shrinks down and collapses into a pellet. If I use `flex`, I feel like I need to tweak `flex` property to my need. Is there a simple way to fix it?(I want them to always occupy two lines evenly with the gap in between in response to the changing viewport width)

```css
.square {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 60px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.square .content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-of-round">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: display:inline-block and width: 60px ?

Comment: Thanks it kind of works. Could you explain a bit why display:inline-block and max-width: 60px won't work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `width` not `max-width` when using `inline-block`. Unlike block elements, inline-block doesn't take the full parent width so `max-width` will have no effect

```css
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.square .content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-of-round">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.square {
width:10vw;
max-width:60px;aspect-ratio:1;
  
  
  margin-bottom:3vw;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
}
.number-of-round{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;}
```

```html
<div class="number-of-round">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="number-of-round">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content flex flex-center">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you look at the outcome/result of your snippet? – those aren't squares...

Comment: +1 from me, scales well and achieves the spacing required. Not being square is trivial, easily modified with `aspect-ratio: 1;` in the .square style rules (and may not be as important to the questioner as the horizontal layout anyway).